# Suddenly Cut From Remote Desktop Session and Can't Log Back Into Any Session

Tags: windows-8, remote-desktop, azure

I was literally in the middle of a remote desktop session doing work when all the sudden the session disconnected and now I can not log back into any session anywhere. I know it's not just the domain as I am unable to even log into other domains as well. I did do an update earlier today... but it's weird that it would be working fine one minute then cut me out the next.

The exception I am getting is "Remote Desktop can't connect ot the remote computer for one of the following reasons..." in researching I found some older posts which pointed to older updates... but nothing recent. All the machines I am trying to login to are Azure VM's my machine is using Windows 8.1

Just to be sure I uninstalled the newest update to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have a tight deadline to make today. Also please note that I am a developer... so I am still learning the technical side of Servers and Networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours and hours trying to figure this out... I set my routers firewall setting to low and all the sudden it started working again.

This doesn't tell me why all the sudden it cut me off in the middle of a session.... but it will have to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the remote desktop service is currently running. If it is restart the service, if not then start it. Then do the classic "Have you tried turning it off and on again"

Comment: Following your suggestion I tried it and am still getting the same.

Comment: Was the service running?

Comment: Yes... it was running. I restarted it... then tried, nothing. I then completely stopped it and then started it again and still nadda.

Comment: The service I restarted and stopped etc. was "Remote Desktop Service"... this is correct? as I see several other "Remote" services?

Comment: The only other thing that I can think of is that the remote desktop licencing is expired. Has anyone else been able to connect to the VM's?

Comment: 3 different domains handled by 3 different customers... I can not log into any of them. I hate to ask a customer that question but I guess I will have to here shortly.